# Get node status from system tables

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I'm using DataStax c++ cassandra driver. As far as I can see there is no special functions regarding checking node status in the driver API. Nodetool utility achieves this via JMX extensions. But I suppose it will be quite painful to implement this in C++. Is there any other way to get this info (at least online/offline) preferably via querying `system` tables.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JMX to HTTP bridge called Jolokia which is loaded into any Java application as a JAR file and it exports all JMX variables through a dedicated HTTP port.

I'm using it successfully to monitor Cassandra runtime parameters with InfluxDB/Telegraf.

You can use it in your C++ app more easily as it's normal HTTP.